Is there a complexity class defined as fixed Boolean combinations of problems in $\mathsf{BPP} \cup \mathsf{BH}$?
I have 2 type of decision problems: either in $\mathsf{BPP}$ or in $\mathsf{NP}$; and I want to decide fixed Boolean combinations of them. Since $\mathsf{BPP}$ is closed under Boolean combinations and Boolean combinations of $\mathsf{NP}$ problems yield the definition of $\mathsf{BH}$, I am looking for the smallest class containing $\mathsf{BPP} \cup \mathsf{BH}$ and closed under fixed Boolean combinations. A possible definition for such class $C$ could be:

$L \in \mathsf{BPP} \cup \mathsf{BH}$, then $L \in C$
$L_1, L_2 \in C$, then $L_1 \wedge L_2 \in C$ and $L_1 \vee L_2 \in C$

Studying subset relations in the Complexity Zoo I have found that:

$C \subseteq S_2^{\mathsf{P}}$, $C \subseteq \mathsf{P}^{QMA}$, $C \subseteq \mathsf{BPP}_{path}$

$\mathsf{P}^{\mathsf{NP}[log]} \subseteq S_2^{\mathsf{P}}$, $\mathsf{P}^{\mathsf{NP}[log]} \subseteq \mathsf{P}^{QMA}$, $\mathsf{P}^{\mathsf{NP}[log]} \subseteq \mathsf{BPP}_{path}$.


But I think $\mathsf{P}^{\mathsf{NP}[log]} \not \subseteq C$ holds, so It would be interesting to find a similar class to $C$.
Also, $C$ should be subset of something like $\mathsf{BPP}^{\mathsf{NP}[1]}$ (a candidate for $C$) or something like $\mathsf{P}^{\mathsf{NP}\cup\mathsf{BPP}}$.
It is worth mentioning that my problems in $\mathsf{BPP}$ are polynomial size Boolean combinations of problems in $\mathsf{RP}$, so my original problem is also contained in $\mathsf{P}^{\mathsf{NP}}$. But the idea of $C$ is that it is more tracktable than $\mathsf{P}^{\mathsf{NP}}$, because I have to solve a fixed amount of $\mathsf{NP}$ problems and a polynomial amount of them that I can approximate in polynomial time.

There clear is such a class: you just defined it. But I haven’t seen this in the literature. In terms of common classes, you probably won’t get better upper bounds than what you already discovered.

In the final para, when you write $\mathsf{BPP}^{\mathsf{NP}[1]}$ do you mean just one query to the oracle (the usual meaning of that notation, e.g. https://doi.org/10.1006/jcss.1999.1647), or did you want to write something like $\mathsf{BPP}^{\mathsf{NP}[O(1)]}$? Also, $D=\mathsf{P}^{\mathsf{NP} \cup \mathsf{BPP}}$ usually means $L \in D$ iff there exists $L' \in \mathsf{NP} \cup \mathsf{BPP}$ such that $L \in \mathsf{P}^{L'}$. I think you meant more like $\mathsf{P}^{\mathsf{NP} \oplus \mathsf{BPP}}$ (meaning the tagged disjoint union / pairing operation on languages).

And actually, even with just one query, I think maybe your class is incomparable to $\mathsf{BPP}^{\mathsf{NP}[1]}$...since that class contains $\mathsf{MA}$, but it doesn't look to me like your class contains $\mathsf{MA}$.

Yes I meant $\mathsf{BPP}^{\mathsf{NP}[O(1)]}$. As for the second class $D$, I meant that if a TM had 2 oracle tapes (one for $\mathsf{BPP}$ and one for $\mathsf{NP}$) I could resolve the problem generating a fixed-size truth table that maps a fixed amount of nonadaptive queries (to those oracles) to the correct output. Since in $\mathsf{BPP}^{\mathsf{NP}[O(1)]}$ I could solve a polynomial amount of $\mathsf{BPP}$ problems, seems like a subset could be enough (the $C$ class).

Oh sorry, I shouldn't have said incomparable. I just meant that $\mathsf{BPP}^{\mathsf{NP}[1]}$ already seems to strictly contain your class since it contains MA but your class doesn't seem to. For the class D, what you describe is equivalent to $\mathsf{P}^{\mathsf{NP} \oplus \mathsf{BPP}}$ (but not to $\mathsf{P}^{\mathsf{NP} \cup \mathsf{BPP}}$, which is equal to $\mathsf{P}^{\mathsf{NP}} \cup \mathsf{P}^\mathsf{BPP} = \mathsf{P}^{\mathsf{NP}} \cup \mathsf{BPP}$, essentially by definition).

Thanks! Do you have any reference for MA in relation with some of this classes? I think since MA does not contain $\mathsf{BH}$, $C \subseteq MA$ should not hold. I think $\mathsf{BPP}^{\mathsf{NP}[O(1)]}$ is indeed a good upperbound for $C$.

I am thinking $L \in \mathsf{BH}^{\mathsf{NP}[O(1)]}$ iff there exists a polynomial time randomized algorithm $M$ with input $x$ and coin toss $s \in {0,1}^{poly(|x|)}$, and a language $L' \in \mathsf{NP}$ such that:


$M$ produces $q \in O(1)$ nonadaptive query strings $(z_1, ..., z_q)$ and a truth table $t: {0,1}^{q} \to {0,1}$ such that $M(x) = t(L'(z_1), ..., L'(z_q))$.


$M(x) = L(x)$ with a probability of at least $\frac{2}{3}$ over all $s$.


